# How to use String array to populate enum friendly string

Tags: java, enums

I coded to populate my enum with Friendly String names, e.g. Swimming Time, Hiking Time...

```
public enum SeasonTypeEnum {
    summer("Swimming Time"),
    auturm("Hiking Time"),
    winter("Skiing Time"),
    spring("Planting Time");

    private String friendlyName;

    private SeasonTypeEnum(String friendlyName){
        this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return friendlyName;
    }
}
```

However, I'm thinking of storing these stings in an array and extracting from there. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely an `enum` is the best solution however,

The way I would write an array like this

```
static final String[] seasons = 
              "Swimming Time,Hiking Time,Skiing Time,Planting Time".split(",");
```

if you want to extract from the enums you can do this

```
static final SeasonTypeEnum[] VALUES = values();

public static String friendlyNameFor(int id) {
    return VALUES[id].friendlyName;
}
```

Comment: Or just call `values()`; unless the code makes millions of calls per second, the performance gain by creating the constant array will be negligible.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Since your IDE can do this refactor for you, I would write it as `value()[id]` but use the `Introduce a Constant` refactor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Enum.values() for this.

Example:

```
SeasonTypeEnum[] vals = SeasonTypeEnum.values();
String[] strs = new String[vals.length];
for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
   strs[i] = vals[i].toString();
}
```

Or the other way around:

```
   public static SeasonTypeEnum getByStr(String val) {
      for (SeasonTypeEnum e : values()) {
         if (e.friendlyName.equals(val)) return e;
      }

      return null;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store friendly strings in private static array and correlate with enum entries by adding index as entry field:

```
public enum SeasonTypeEnum {

    private static String seasons = new String[] {"Swimming Time", "Hiking Time", "Skiing Time", "Planting Time"};

    summer(0),
    auturm(1),
    winter(2),
    spring(3);

    private int index;

    private SeasonTypeEnum(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return seasons[index];
    }
}
```